# Can i develop iphone application using vmware with mac os installed on it?

Tags: ios, macos, windows-7, virtual-machine

My OS is windows 7 and I want to develop IOS applications without buying a MAC. Can I install MAC OS on a virtual machine for development ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I did this for 6 months before buying my first Mac.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have another question. My laptop has 2 GB RAM and processor Intel Core 2 Duo. Will the vmware with MAC OS work on it or it will be very slow ?

Comment: It will work but it will be very slow. I had 6GB or RAM and the top processor my laptop could take and it was ok. I found it was much cheaper to upgrade the ram and get a 2nd hand CPU than buying a mac. But eventually bit the bullet.

Comment: XCode Development and IPhone USB detection Working fine with Cachem's MacOS 10.8 under VMWare Workstation 8.0.4

Comment: Which VMWare is a best suit for windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X can be installed in a VM, although it's only officially supported in a Mac-on-Mac manner by any of the big players due to the license of OS X. There are methods to install OS X on non-OS X virtual machines, but they're quite a bit more complicated than normal.

Lifehacker has a tutorial for [VirtualBox](http://lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows), and iHackintosh for [VMware](http://www.ihackintosh.com/2009/12/install-snow-leopard-in-vmware-7-windows-edition/). I've not tried these myself, so I'm not sure how well they work from personal experience (I've seen many accounts saying it works fairly well). I've only run OS X in Parallels (on top of OS X), and it was sluggish on my MacBook Air, but that was most likely largely due to not having enough memory to comfortably run both OSes at the same time (4GB split evenly). Also, I don't believe accelerated graphics is supported on any hypervisor, so that will also hamper performance. If you have a fairly decent system, though, it should be able to handle Xcode fairly well. Xcode doesn't require any special hardware support for developing iOS apps, so it'll run as long as you can get OS X running fine. To deploy to an iOS device, you'll need to set up USB forwarding (which varies based on the VM software) so Xcode can see it. After that point, everything else is the same (anything graphically intensive will run like crap in the simulator, though).

You'll still need a copy of OS X, which AFAIK (IANA, though!), you're not supposed to install on a non-Mac computer (either as host or guest OS!).

Comment: Xcode works fine in a Virtual Machine. I added a bit more to explicitly state that.